# Python Pandas: Converting Dataframes and setting Indexes

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, unix-timestamp, datetimeindex

I have to do the tasks below, but some parts do not work out properly. Here are the steps:

1. Converting a dataframe with unix timestamps to a dataframe with datetime values, works with the following code:
   `datetime_df = pd.to_datetime(unix_df, unit='s')`
2. Resampling the datetime with `smpl = datetime_df[0].resample('10min')`
3. Converting it back to unix timestamp format with: `unix_df =
   datetime_df.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9`

Step 1 and 3 work, but step 2 doesn't work because Python tells me it needs a DateTimeIndex and I don't know how to set it. The strange thing is that the index completely disappears after `to_datetime`, so I tried creating a list and then making a dataframe from it again, but it still didn't work. Somebody can help me?

Comment: `datetime_df.set_index('your_column', inplace=True)` where 'your_column' is the name of the datetime column

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga. Unfortunately I get the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: then you are working with a Series, not a DataFrame.

Comment: `to_datatime` makes a series of the frame. I can convert it back to a frame with `frame = pd.DataFrame(seriesobject)` but I still can not use resample on it and get the following TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: the use the code I showed you to set the index on your datframe

Comment: Please include a sample of your data: read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)